Have Assad or his allies commented on evidence of Turkey's alleged support for HTS? If not, what do we know about why not?
The Syrian Civil War has come back into the international headlines in early December 2024 due to major advances by Hayat Tahrir al-Sham (HTS) .
AFP reports that President Assad made a statement in response during a phone call with Iranian President Pezeshkian blaming "the United States and the West".
However, HTS is officially designated a terrorist organization by the US. If it is true that they are supporting HTS anyway, that should be a big deal. On the other hand, there are decisive statements in the press from Western analysts suggesting that HTS enjoys at least some degree of passive support from Turkey. From the New York Times:

[HTS] has failed to establish ties with most foreign powers. One exception is Turkey, which borders Idlib and controls a broad expanse of neighboring northern Syria, making it essential to the group’s ability to keep Idlib running.
Turkish bases in Idlib and Turkish artillery stationed on the Turkish side of the border have served to buffer the group’s territory from Syrian government troops, said Robert Ford, a former U.S. ambassador to Syria who is now a senior fellow at the Middle East Institute. Humanitarian aid, gas, weapons and even military-style uniforms all flow into Idlib from Turkey, he said. Analysts said the group and Turkey also tacitly share information and advice.
[...]
Analysts said the rebels needed at least a tacit go-ahead from Turkey, which has been frustrated that talks with Mr. al-Assad about the return of Syrian refugees in Turkey have stalled. Looking for leverage in negotiations and perhaps territory to push refugees into, the analysts said, Turkey most likely encouraged the rebels to move.
“My guess is the Turkish calculation goes something like this: Every day that this offensive continues and moves further and opens up more space, every day, that’s another 5,000 refugees that we can send back to Syria,” Mr. Ford of the Middle East Institute said.

I found it intriguing that Assad would blame the West without clear evidence, when it is far more likely that their neighbor Turkey does have a role. Has this been addressed anywhere? Is there any specific reason or expert commentary on why Syria and it's allies might be inclined to avoid condemning Turkey directly? Does Syria claim that the (allegedly responsible) West is trying to deflect blame onto Turkey?

Turkey's a member of Nato which may well count as "the West".

This is why "the West" is a vague and not particularly useful term (as are similar ones like "the East.") Is Syria trying to blame Türkiye alone, Türkiye with the help of (part of? all of?) (the EU? NATO?),  part of (the EU? NATO?) alone but excluding Türkiye?

Turkey only has a so-so level of control over the various faction that make up the SNA, which is officially supported by Turkey. Recently there have been some defections (to the HTS camp) from SNA after certain disagreements. How genuine these are it's hard to say. Also, some of the fighters taking down Russian flags were speaking Turkish... See https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/89981/18373 Whether Turkey has their own "little green men" spread among the SNA and/or HTS would be difficult to confirm, and the West probably not too enticed to look into it.

The Kurds (SDF) too have accused Turkey of being behind the HTS offensive. Especially since the SNA started fighting the SDF as part of the land grab that followed the rout in Assad's camp.

"I found it intriguing that Assad would blame the West without clear evidence". I don't find it surprising/intriguing at all. It's part and parcel of the Russia/Assad propaganda to make claims like that.

Unsurprisingly, Iran has made similar claims https://www.jpost.com/middle-east/article-831434

We(the CIA) have already supported terrorist organisations while denoting them as "terrorists".Relations are not that simple.

In fact I blame the CIA for the situation we are in today.We are the most powerful country in the world(by far) and these warmonging greedy CIA want to set the world on fire.CIA is no longer controlled by the government , it is a private intelligence agency (basically mercenaries) having the resources of a country , yet ...

If history is to be taken seriously, there would be nothing unusual in the US supporting anti-Assad forces, as a matter of countering Iranian influence in the region, even if these forces are Islamists/terrorists/etc. Expecting the US government to officially acknowledge such a support is a different matter - perhaps, we'll know in a few decades, when the relevant documents are declassified (Alternatively, it might be written explicitly somewhere in Arab, Persian, Russian, Chinese or even Swiss newspapers - but these are not accepted as evidence in this community.)


AFP reports that President Assad made a statement in response during a phone call with Iranian President Pezeshkian blaming "the United States and the West". [...]
I found it intriguing that Assad would blame the West without clear evidence [...]

I don't see what's intriguing about it, especially given the context of a conversation with Iran. Iran itself has  made similar claims on more than one occasion:

“The new movements of Takfiri-terrorist groups are part of the plot of the US and the illegitimate Zionist regime,” Mohammad Bagher Qalibaf, speaker of the Iranian parliament, said Friday in a post on his X account. [...]
Iranian Foreign Minister Abbas [...] Araghchi has also warned that the HTS advance is part of a “broader scheme by the Israeli regime and the United States to destabilize the West Asian region,” IRNA reported. He made his comments in a call with Russian Foreign Minister Sergey Lavrov.

Presumably it's easier and more motivating for their base for Iranian propaganda to blame the US and Zionists for HTS than it is for them to blame Turkey
with whom Iran has a more complicated relationship marked by both competition and cooperation. Reportedly it's been rather rare for Iran to openly blame Turkey for anything. One such occasion was when (reportely) Kurds blew up an oil pipeline from Iran and Turkey refused Iran's offer to repair it.
Also, the Iranian and Turkish FM have held a join press conference just today (Dec 2) on their efforts to bring some kind of ceasefire or deal.

Both Fidan and Araghchi said Turkey, Iran and Russia would convene a new three-way meeting to address the conflict in Syria.

It's somewhat apparent that painting Turkey as something other than part of the West is more conductive to Iran's approach to these matters.
Whether Assad truly believes that the US is behind HTS is less important than the fact that he needs Iranian and their proxies support to stay in power and regain lost ground. (So, he'll parrot their words on that.) It's already been reported that Shia PMF militias from Iraq (Kataib Hezbollah and Fatemiyoun) have crossed the border to join the fight against HTS.


Question:
Have Assad or his allies commented on evidence of Turkey's alleged support for HTS? If not, what do we know about why not?

No.  Turkey which controls the Bosporus strait is in a position to affect something Russia cares significantly more about than Syria.  Turkey is part of NATO which makes it's neutrality in administering the Bosphorus, failure to economically sanction Russia, and continued close ties with Russia all very important to Russia.  Now with Finland and Sweeden in NATO and with the Baltic Sea looking more and more like a NATO lake; Turkey which controls Russia's access to the Mediterranean Sea is of even more importance both economically and militarily.
The lack of public mention of Turkey's support for HTS likely reflects this intricate and sensitive nature of regional alliances and ongoing diplomatic efforts and general appreciation for Turkey's multifaceted approach to the Ukrainian War and Russia's aggression.

Perhaps you wanted to say "two-faced" instead of "multifaceted"...

@user13964273, No I meant multifaced as in complex and many moving parts.  Turkey's struggled with inflation, peaking at over 85% in late 2022. As of November 2024, it eased slightly to 47.1%.  I think what you are seeing is Turkey trying to look after it's own economic interests at a time when it's economy is an existential threat to the regime, with the backdrop of ongoing tensions with the West and overtures from the East.
